# how to persist --set key values to values.yaml in helm install/upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

how to persist the parameter key values to values.yaml file while use command line to set the values.helm install . --name test --set image.tag=2020 --set image.version=20 how to update this image.tag and image.version values to values.yaml? dry run will give the result but wont update the values.yaml

Comment: You should be able to edit the `values.yaml` file with your favorite text editor, if it's a chart you control, or supply an alternate YAML file through the `helm install -f` option.  Would either of these approaches meet your needs?

Comment: @DavidMaze i gauss that will not work here, what i am trying is all configurable key  values i am passing using --set command and i want to update those values to values.yaml so anyone can see that what values has been used to install helm chart. i am passing almost 20-30 key in single command  and i want to persist that values into values.yaml so user can use it later for upgrade or so on.. i have research lot on google but couldn't find the easy way. may be i need to write a python or bash script, do u have any idea?

Comment: `helm get values` will retrieve them from the cluster.  There is a `helm upgrade --reuse-values` option that will start from that as a base.  The other useful observation is that valid JSON is also valid YAML, so you can pass a JSON file to the `helm install -f` option, which sometimes is a little easier to script.

Comment: I agree with David, If you control the chart, you can can modify the values.yaml, otherwise the `helm upgrade --reuse-values` will keep your values during upgrade, have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, does helm upgrade --reuse-values update values to the key in values.yaml, i am going to try this, the reason to this is end user doesn't know what values has be used during installation(as installation done using --set) so if they want to upgrade they might face an issue, and we are setting up multiple cluster everyday so we need to keep update the values.yaml so end user know that the application deployed with this parameters.

Comment: so, you want to reuse values + merge with new values.yaml file? is it? It would be great if you could edit your question with a end-to-end goal. From original state A, transitional state B (if needed) and goal stage C, this way we can help you providing a more meaningful answer, and will enable you to help others with similar issues as well.

Comment: @willrof yes i want to update/merge key values in values.yaml, let me explain e2e scenario, so i am passing --set arguments to pass key values to values.yaml Ex. helm install --name abc --set image=abc --set version-123 so this way key values will be passed in installation but the key values will not updated to actually values.yaml file, so  when the second person has to do update helm release they might don't know which values has been used during installation so some how if its possible to update this into values.yaml at the same time when u passed to installation?

Comment: @willrof so when we do --dry-run for any helm installation by passing key values using command line --set we can see two different things 1) USER-SUPPLIED VALUES: shows only the values we pass using --set 2) COMPUTED VALUES: shows the updated(passed to configmap)  values that are matched with the key in values.yaml.  but this values are not actually updated in values.yaml, since it just dry-run, but if there is a possibility actual update COMPUTED VALUES to values.yaml?

Answer (score 5):

**Helm** is a package manager, and it's all about automating deployment of kubernetes apps. It's designed to be somewhat static, and only being changed by the creator of the chart.

- [Values Files](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/) provides access to values passed into the chart. Its contents come from multiple sources:

  > - The `values.yaml` file **in the chart**
  > - If this is a subchart, the `values.yaml` file **of a parent chart**
  > - **A values file if passed into helm install** or helm upgrade with the `-f` flag (`helm install -f myvals.yaml ./mychart`)
  > - **Individual parameters** passed with `--set` (such as `helm install --set foo=bar ./mychart`)
- This is the base Hierarchy of the values files, but there is more to it:

[image]
*Kudos to the creator of this image, unfortunately I wasn't able to find the author to credit him.*

- You can't change the chart `values.yaml` file exacly as you are thinking, because the original `values.yaml` will keep the state desired by the creator of the chart.
- The flowchart above is all about changes made during `helm install` or `helm upgrade`.

---

I'll try to exemplify your use scenario:

- Chart 1 has the default values with:

```
image: original-image
version: original-version
```

- You decided to deploy this chart changing some values using `--set` as in your example `helm install --name abc --set image=abc --set version-123`. Resulting in:

```
image: abc
version: 123
```

- Then you want to upgrade the chart and modify the `version` value but keeping the other values as set, you run: `helm upgrade --set version=124 --reuse-values, here is the result values in effect:

```
image: abc
version: 124
```

**NOTE:** As we seen in the flowchart, **if you don't specify --reuse-values** it will reset the values that were not `--set` during the upgrade to back to the original of the chart. In this case `image` would again be `original-image`.

---

So, to wrap up your main question:

> how to persist --set key values to values.yaml in helm install/upgrade?

You can persist the `--set` values during the `upgrade` by always using `--reuse-values`, however the changes will never be commited to the original template of `values.yaml` file.

If you are the owner of the chart, It's the recommended behavior that you create release versions of your chart, so you can keep track of what were the default in each version.

I hope it helps clarifying the issue.

If I can help you any further, let me know in the comments.

Comment: I believe the origin of the diagram is this Medium article by Harry Cao: https://medium.com/@kcatstack/understand-helm-upgrade-flags-reset-values-reuse-values-6e58ac8f127e

Answer (score 0):

You can cpy the stuff from kubes when the depl/change is ready with kubectl get  -o yaml
it is not quite the same of course.